# Online site for manual software testing

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, testcase

Does anyone know of an online site or application that can be used to test manual testing skills? I am looking at site where techniques like BVA, negative, positive, equivalence partitioning etc. can be tested on the fields. If it can provide a confirmed list of bugs that are present, than that would help to see the coverage.

Require this for testing the skills of my students who are learning testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find few more  -

[LINK1](http://qualitypointtech.net/timesheetdemo/index.php)

[LINK2](http://newtours.demoaut.com/)

[LINK3](http://blazedemo.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The following come to mind:

[Testing Challenge](http://testingchallenges.thetestingmap.org/index.php)

[Guru99](http://www.guru99.com/)

[Tuesday Test Trials](https://www.utest.com/search-result/all/tuesdaytesttrials)

Answer (score 0):

The following online sites are very much useful in order to test QA skill (manual and automation both):

http://toolsqa.com/

https://www.qatutor.com/